# How can I filter and junk a certain domain's recipients in exim?

Tags: exim

I have found that a significant number of users of a system have set an email address addresses to an address with the top level domain .test. As a interim measure, I don't want to attempt to deliver these mails at all and I just want to silently dump them to the mail equivalent of /dev/null.

Is there way to configure exim to just junk these recipients?

(I need to educate people not to do this and not to choose some other random email address when QA testing but in the mean time I want to prevent delivery attempts for all recipients at this junk tld.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a rewrite rule, these rules rewrite anything that's in the ".qp" TLD to point to the local host, the first two override the local part to just dump it to an alias the last one sends the rest to the same user on this machine.

The .qp TLD is one of the "ISO 3166-1 alpha-2" country codes that is specifically allocated for local use.

```
begin rewrite

supp@*.qp            Support         FhQ
Development@*.qp     Support         FhQ
*@*.qp               $local_part     FhQ
```

The flags on the end say what to rewrite ...

```
E       rewrite all envelope fields
F       rewrite the envelope From field
T       rewrite the envelope To field
b       rewrite the Bcc: header
c       rewrite the Cc: header
f       rewrite the From: header
h       rewrite all headers
r       rewrite the Reply-To: header
s       rewrite the Sender: header
t       rewrite the To: header
```

The "Q" means that just a local part is allowed in the 'rewrite to' part.